# How to Show Posts created by logged in user to him?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This looks to be fairly straight forward but I am still not able to get it done

I have Devise installed and have User and Website classes where User creates websites.

Now i want the logged in user to see what sites he has created. This is the controller code

```
def index
@websites = Website.find(:all)
end
```

and the index.html.erb is

```
<%= render :partial=> "website_list", :locals=> {:website => @Website} %>
```

What do I need to change in controller index to show sites created by the logged in user only

EDIT - OK, I am able to create the foreign key user_id in websites table using migrations but the values for user_id are all NIL. Any idea why ?

Edit 2 - Here are my fields

CONTROLLER
dashboard_controller.rb

```
@websites = current_user.websites.all
```

website_controller.rb
This was created by scaffolding, I have not edited anything in it

MODEL
user.rb

```
has_many :websites
```

website.rb

```
attr_accessible :description, :url, :user_id (**I added :user_id here**)
belongs_to :user
```

VIEWS

```
<%= render :partial=> "website_list", :locals=> {:website => @Website} %>
```

Migration

```
add_column :websites, :user_id, :integer
```

I am not sure what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
@websites = current_user.websites.all
```

Comment: Hi, getting this error - "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'websites.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `websites`.* FROM `websites`  WHERE `websites`.`user_id` = 1", I guess I need to create foreign key, can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: OK, I am able to create the foreign key user_id in websites table using migrations but the values for user_id are all NIL. Any idea why ?

Comment: At any time, You can use current_user.websites in Controller. Actually you dont have user_id column in Website table. Rails plugin Devise itself handle this. Please see http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise for further details.

Comment: I am still not able to show the list of websites and it looks like I have done everything right! the user_id column in websites table is filled with NULL and when I manually change NULL to some user ID, then the code DO show the list of websites. I have added some more info in the above question, can you please look into and find possible problems ? Thanks

Comment: To show the current users websites, you should change the create action in websites_controller. Like this => @website = current_user.websites.new(params[:website]). Then you can show the current user websites.

Comment: FINALLY, it is working! You rock Rajeswari. One question though, I had to create a migration to add a user_id column, is this the standard way to do it ? do I have to add a column _id for every foreign key through migration ? thanks

Comment: It is not needed to migrate separate column for foreign key. Devise itself will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@websites = Website.find(:all, :conditions => ['user_id = ?',current_user.id.to_s])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this ..

```
    @websites = Website.where("client_id='101'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in your create action in the controller - you are saving websites without connection to users.